# How to replace null collections in input model with empty ones in ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an input model from body:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Books { get; set; }
}
```

When user sends

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "books": null
}
```

I Books property is null, but I want it to be empty list. How to do it once for all the controllers and models?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core knows how to bind the the parameters to the constructor.
This is not the best approach, but it is the one I decided to go with:

```cs
public class User
{
    public User(string name, List<string> books)
    {
        Name = name;
        Books = books ?? new List<string>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Books { get; set; }
}
```